# Lookup GID/GUID of remote infiniband client

Tags: infiniband

I have an application written in C that opens a TCP connection from the client to the server via IPoIB.
I need to look up the GUID/GID of the client from the server, preferably without invoking an external application.

Is there a way of doing this via ibverbs or such given we only have a TCP connection open at this point (and all the usual information associated with one)?

Answer (score 1):

you can setup client to send its GUIDs as a direct message or in response of some kind of flag from the server. code for retreiving all GUIDs from client side can be found on this link
[rdma_count_devices](http://www.rdmamojo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/count_devices.c)

however, you need to program a logic yourself that how and when this list is send to the server.
Moreover, I would like to suggest use RDMA CM to make connections in infiniband architecture rather using TCP sockets.